# Rails helpers return just strings. How would I have it return HTML?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to return this in it's predictable HTML way :

```
'Page Total ' + @total_on_page + tag('br') + 'Total All Pages'.html_safe + @total
```

But instead it just parses the `br/` as plain text. How do I return a working HTML version of `br/` ?

Expected Output :

```
Page Total $123123
Total All Pages $12312312
```

Actual Output :

```
Page Total $8,296.42<br />Total All Pages$23,669.73
```

Comment: Expected output, current output?

Comment: I wouldn't rely on instance variables in a helper, you should probably pass them in as arguments instead.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The .html_safe at the end is applying only to the last string, not the overall string. You want something more like this:

```
('Page Total ' + @total_on_page + tag('br') + 'Total All Pages' + @total).html_safe
```